# Apache Flex SDK Installer does nothing (on Mac OS 10.12.6)

Tags: macos, apache, apache-flex, installation

I've installed the Apache Flex SDK Installer from https://flex.apache.org/installer.html as you can see from the following image. When I double click it, it does absolutely nothing.

Any help gratefully received, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have your same problem in my MacBook Pro 2015 running 10.12.6. I double-click the installer and it does not run. However, I tried it on an older Mac mini 2012 with 10.12.6 and it runs fine. I was able to install the SDK and use it. Hence, I don't know what the problem is, but it doesn't seem to be the OS. If I find something, I'll post the answer.

Comment: @baquiano hi: if you've got the SDK there any chance could you just zip it up and send it to me, please? (assuming that it IS just a directory I can dump into my Flash Builder installation)

Comment: I have made some progress on this, I will report back if it's successful.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aibvz-vml9NHimTRVIp6Caw-OmEv Sorry for the late reply. This is the download link for Apache Flex 4.16 SDK.

Comment: thank you @baquiano, I have managed to install SDK in the meantime, but I appreciate you taking the time nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to open app contents:

[image]

Then find the SDK installer and open with Terminal:

[image]

You will then probably been blocked from installing software from an unidentified developer. Go to Systems Preferences > Security & Privacy and click the "Open Anyway" button. You might be asked for your password. Then you might get an error that reads "Unable to load http://flex.apache.org/installer/sdk-installer-config-4.0.xml". Close the installer, then start again. Hopefully the installation will work second time around, it did for me.

Three dropdowns are presented, to select: Flex version; AIR version; and Flash Player version. Ensure these are set to the latest versions (which aren't betas). For me that was: Flex SDk 4.16.0; AIR 26; and Flash Player 26. If you do not do this, when you try to add the SDK to Flash Builder later (via Flash Builder > Preferences > Flash Builder > Installed Flex SDKS > Add...) you will find yourself plagued by the error discussed in this forum thread: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-35289

You will be asked to choose a directory for the installation, one which: 1. is acceptable (although no definition of acceptability is outlined); and 2. is empty. I made a new directory entitled "4.16.0" in `/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/sdks` which the installer was happy with.

After which there were no further problems. Not with the installation anyway. Flash Builder itself failed to open after this. That is a new problem which I asked about, and which was successfully answered here: [Flash Builder 4.7 does not open after installing Apache Flex SDK 4.16.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319193/flash-builder-4-7-does-not-open-after-installing-apache-flex-sdk-4-16-0)