# Flash Builder 4.7 does not open after installing Apache Flex SDK 4.16.0

Tags: java, apache, apache-flex, flash-builder

Having installed Apache Flex SDK 4.16.0, I open Flash Builder 4.7 to see this error dialog message:

```
An error has occurred.
See the log file at <dir>/.log.
```

The .log in question is 1676 lines long, starts like this:

```
!SESSION 2017-09-20 10:59:34.184 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/<REDACTED>/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/<REDACTED>/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2017-09-20 10:59:42.241
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-20 10:59:42.867
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.adobe.flexbuilder.project (68).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.internal.FlexProjectCore.start() of bundle com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
```

and ends like this:

```
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 149 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2017-09-20 10:59:43.401
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchActivityHelper$4
```

My set up is:

```
OS:        Sierra 10.12.6
Hardware:  MBP Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015
Processor: 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory:    16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics:  Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
```

I not proficient with Eclipse or Java^ and therefore do not know what else I can tell you. Any help gratefully received, thank you.

^ *I am Swift (now) and ActionScript (formerly) programmer*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a new or empty Workspace to see if that works.

There are some tips on running [Running Adobe Flash Builder on Win and Mac with Java 7/8](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2016/09/running-adobe-flash-builder-on-mac-with-java-78.html#sthash.8FG9pn5V.dpbs)

You may also want to increase the [Java virtual memory settings](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/sluggish-performance-out-memory-errors.html) if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Thanks @AmigaAbattoir I'll give that a go

Comment: Thanks @AmigaAbattoir. I removed the Apache Flex SDK and cleaned up Flash Builder as much as I could but was still getting the error, so I went to your second step, followed the instructions on your "Running Adobe Flash Builder on Win and Mac with Java 7/8" link and Flash Builder is now running again. The problem was not that the Apache Flex SDK caused a problem, but that in order to run the installation process for it I needed to install Ant, which in turn required Java, being version 8.0_144